# Function readmtx on matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to read a matrix that is on my matlab path. I was using the function readmtx but I don't know what to put on 'precision' (mtx = readmtx(fname,nrows,ncols,precision)).
I was wondering if you could help me with that. Or suggest a better way to read the matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read a matrix from text file with `load` command. If the first line include text, that should be started with `%`.

Note that each row of the text file should be values of a row in matrix, which are separated by a space, for Example:

```
%C1 C2 C3
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Then, if you use `load` command you can read the text file into a matrix, something like:

```
myMatrix = load('textFileName.txt')
```

Now, Let's talk about `readmtx` ;)

About precision as described [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/readmtx.html):

Both binary and formatted data files can be read. If the file is binary, the precision argument is a format string recognized by fread. Repetition modifiers such as '40*char' are not supported. If the file is formatted, precision is a fscanf and sscanf-style format string of the form '%nX', where n is the number of characters within which the formatted data is found, and X is the conversion character such as 'g' or 'd'. Fortran-style double-precision output such as '0.0D00' can be read using a precision string such as '%nD', where n is the number of characters per element. This is an extension to the C-style format strings accepted by sscanf. Users unfamiliar with C should note that '%d' is preferred over '%i' for formatted integers. MATLAB syntax follows C in interpreting '%i' integers with leading zeros as octal. Formatted files with line endings need to provide the number of trailing bytes per row, which can be 1 for platforms with carriage returns or linefeed (Macintosh, UNIX®), or 2 for platforms with carriage returns and linefeeds (DOS).

Check this example also:

Write and read a binary matrix file:

```
fid = fopen('binmat','w');
fwrite(fid,1:100,'int16');
fclose(fid);
mtx = readmtx('binmat',10,10,'int16')

mtx =
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20
    21    22    23    24    25    26    27    28    29    30
    31    32    33    34    35    36    37    38    39    40
    41    42    43    44    45    46    47    48    49    50
    51    52    53    54    55    56    57    58    59    60
    61    62    63    64    65    66    67    68    69    70
    71    72    73    74    75    76    77    78    79    80
    81    82    83    84    85    86    87    88    89    90
    91    92    93    94    95    96    97    98    99   100

mtx = readmtx('binmat',10,10,'int16',[2 5],3:2:9)

mtx =
    13    15    17    19
    23    25    27    29
    33    35    37    39
    43    45    47    49
```

Comment: One of the things that I need is to store the information of the matrix in a string or a vector maybe, like [number that appears on the matrix, number of the row, number of the column]
Which in your example would be something like:
[1, 1, 1]
[2, 1, 2]
[3, 1, 3]
and so on..

Comment: Why you wanna store number of rows and cols? You only need to store the values. Once you load the matrix from a file into a variable, you can access the number of rows and cols by `size` method

Comment: I need to resolve the minimum spanning tree problem. I thought I could go through the matrix, see the minimum cost in each row, then  connect all the subtrees. Then analise how many subtrees there were and if there were more than 1, I would try to find the minimum cost to connect them

Comment: There's a matlab method called `graphminspantree` which is for finding minimum spanning tree. Check it's source code. It will help you a lot. Note that you do can go through the matrix with `for` and index of elements.

Comment: Also you can check this [link](http://www.codeforge.com/article/243803) for matlab implementation of Kruskal minimum spanning tree algorithm